# allowableValues From a File

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I might be going about this the wrong way, but is there a way to populate the allowableValues string from a json file?

Every method I've tried in reading from a file/json ends up with me having to call a method like toString(), resulting in a non-constant result.  Swagger won't allow non-constant allowableValues, but it seems silly to me that I would have to manually update this list programmatically rather than in an external file in order to add to this list.

I suspect there isn't a compile time strategy that would work here, but just thought I would ask.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve information")
@RequestMapping(value={"dothis/thing"}, method=RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public JsonNode applicationList(HttpServletRequest request,
                                       @ApiParam(name="input_name", value="Input Name", allowableValues = LIST_OF_VALUES) @RequestParam (required = false) String input_name) throws GeneralException {
```

Comment: If `allowableValues` is an annotation element then no, you can't assign it a value read from a file; note this is a limitation of annotations, not Swagger. Does Swagger provide ways to configure the code other than annotations? If so, try using one of those. It may also help if you provide a [mre] in the question so as to make the question less ambiguous.

Comment: I've included an example.  I do not know if there is another way for me to achieve my goal of populating the list of values in Swagger's drop down menu for an input.